# A double integration

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

As part of a physics calculation, I have been unable to make progress due to being faced with the following integral $$\int_0^1 dx \int_0^{1-x} dy \frac{1}{-x^2+y^2+x-y+a(x+y)},$$ where $a$ is an external variable, treated as a constant within the integration.

I have given it to Mathematica of course but it can only return an integral result (over $x$) involving arctan after performing the integration over $y$. Is it possible to make progress with this on an analytic level or something else I could try to obtain the result?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried changing variables?  $x+y$ and $x-y$ appear frequently in the integrand; they might make good choices for $u$ and $v$.

Comment: @MatthewLeingang Thanks for this suggestion. I gave it a try but as the transformed integrand still contains $u$ and $v$ quadratically along with linear terms and with the integral domain now simply a rotated triangle as compared to the original one in the $x-y$ plane I don't think it helps :/

Comment: @CAF The transformed integral may still contain them quadratically in the denominator, but if you hold one variable fixed (as is done in the intermediate step when evaluating a double integral) the other variable appears only linearly, which means that you will be evaluating an integral involving log instead of arctan.  When you say you gave it a try, did you actually attempt to evaluate it, or did you just do the transformation and decide it didn't look simpler?

Comment: @Aaron Thanks for your comment also. Yes, I tried to evaluate it but failed to make a simplification which resulted in what you say. However, after one integration I am getting logs of quadratic variables divided by linear terms. Can I just check I did the transformation correct? My integral is $$2 \left(\int_{-1}^0 du \int_1^{-u} dv + \int_0^1 du \int_0^u dv \right) \frac{1}{-uv + u + av}$$

Comment: First, I think the Jacobian is 1/2, not 2, second, the transformed region is a triangle bounded by $v=1, u=v, u=-v$, so you can write it as $\int_0^1 dv \int_{-v}^v du$.  Finally, while you will have quadratic things in your logs, you can combine everything together to get a log of a fraction, and a factor of v will cancel, reducing you to an integral roughly of the form $\int \log(\frac{a+x}{a-x})/x$

Comment: Hi @Aaron Thanks for your help earlier. I'm doing a more complicated calculation now in which the integrand is $1/((u-uv)a+vb-u^2c)$, with $a,b,c$ constants. Since $u$ appears quadratically I think it best to integrate over $v$ first. Is the correct rewriting of $\int_0^1 dv \int_{-v}^v du$ in terms of an integral over $v$ first given by $$\int_{-1}^0 du \int_{-u}^1 dv + \int_0^1 du \int_{u}^1 dv$$? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The wanted integral is 
$$ \mathfrak{I}=\iint_{\substack{x,y\geq 0\\x+y\leq 1}}\frac{1}{(x-y)(1-x-y)+a(x+y)}\,dx\,dy $$
hence a natural temptation, in order to simplify the integrand function, is to enforce the substitution $x-y=u, x+y=v$, leading to:
$$ \mathfrak{I} = 2 \int_{0}^{1}\int_{-v}^{v}\frac{1}{u(1-v)+av}\,du\,dv 
\stackrel{u\mapsto v w}{=} 2 \int_{0}^{1}\int_{-1}^{1}\frac{1}{w(1-v)+av}\,dw\,dv $$
then to (by Fubini's theorem):
$$ \mathfrak{I} = 2\int_{-1}^{1}\frac{\log(a)-\log(2w-a)}{a-w}\,dw $$
which depends on the [dilogarithm](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Dilogarithm.html) ($\text{Li}_2$) function.